# Replace "inline style" with a "css class" depending by value of its inline style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My site has CMS, so users can directly insert texts and images. CMS ui allows to float left/right images, applying an inline style to IMG tags.

```
<img src='...' style='float:left'>
```

I would like to detect when an IMG has a `float:left/right` style and replace it with a class in order to declare more properties for it like the following example:

```
.floated-left
{
  float:left;
  margin-right:20px;
  border-left:solid 5px red;
  ....
}
```

I thought about something like this:

```
    if ( $("article").find('img').css('float') == 'left')
    {
       this.addClass('floated-left');
    }
```

But seems that "if clause" never be true. (I know that probably also `this.addClass()` is wrong, but neither `alert()` is never fired at the moment)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to apply more declarations, you could simply achieve that by pure CSS:

```css
img[style*="float:left"],
img[style*="float: left"] {
    margin-right : 20px;
    border-left  : solid 5px red;
}
```

You could play with [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select the valid image/element.

Comment: ohhhh really interesting..... I completely did not know this kind of things!!!! :-)

Comment: Always to prefer css approach +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `attr` instead of `css` for selecting inline styled objects:

```
$('article img').each(function() {
   if ( $(this).attr('style') == 'float:left') {

      $(this).removeAttr('style').addClass('floated-left');
   }
});
```

if some of object's style is different, try this way:

```
$('article img').each(function() {
   if ( $(this).attr('style').indexOf('float:left') > -1 ) {

      var targetedStyle = $(this).attr('style').replace('float:left','');
      $(this).attr('style',targetedStyle).addClass('floated-left');
   }
});
```

Comment: Almost perfect! :-)
But in case that cms applies also other inline styles, like width and height, how to remove only "float:left" declaration?

Comment: mhmmm Firebug return this: 
"`TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined
  if ( $(this).attr('style').indexOf('float:left') > -1 ) {`
"

Comment: it might occur from something else, please share a jsFiddle for us to inspect @LucaDetomi